# multiple queries on huge table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working in redshift (shouldnt matter which DB but  anyway..) i have address table with  which has lot of rows for a member.  The table has about  billion+ rows  . My challenge is based on business logic i might endup doing multiple passes on this data and i am tying to optimize it.

table

| custid. | addrtype | ph# | insert_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |  | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | A1 | 34567 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | A2 | 4444 | 1998-0101 |
| 2 | A1 | 66666 | 1900-01-02 |
| 2 | A3 | 7777 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | . A1 |  | 1999-01-01. |
| 3 | A3 | 123 | 2000-01-01 |

cust1 : i should pick A1 ph#34567
cust 2   i pick A1 even if its older rec because of address type
cust 3 its 123 with address type A3
if all else fails to fetch ph# we get the latest rec based on insert data that has a ph#

so i build bunch of with  tables for each address type and i left-join them back with main query . then i check each sub table for that customer and pick the valid record ( i.e case A1 work has entry then pick that..or check A2 type etc)
case  so you see i am scanning that table quite a few times

```
ex with a with clause:
with latesValidRec-A1 AS (
select custid,insert_date from (
select  custid, max(insert_date) from addr 
where addrtype='A1'  and ph# not null
group by custid) X

)
```

--  similarly other with clause per address type
and then Join them back to main table

```
select * from addr left join latesValidRec-A1 A1max on addr.custid=A1max.custid
```

so we here i am reading big table for each type and in with clause and joining it back

Another approach is just to join with subselect

```
select * from addr left join (
select custid,max(create_date)
where addresstype='A1' and ph# is not null
group by cust_id 
)X  on addr.custid=X.cust_id and addr.create_date = x.create_date
```

which one of the two is better to take multiple passes for this table or is there any other better way

Comment: It sounds like you would probably benefit from using a `window function`, although your question is hard to follow, sample data and desired results as-per a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: "i have to ignore effective date and for a customer".  There is no effective date in the data you have provided.

Comment: yaa i reread my question its terribly put , i will try to reframe it